# ReactInputSelection import from precompiled reactjs

Tags: reactjs, webpack, externals

I want to reduce the size of bundlejs. But when I use precompiled reactjs, I met some problems.

```
    externals: {
        'jquery': 'jQuery',
        'jquery-ui': 'jQueryUI',
        'react': 'React',
        'react/addons': 'React.addons',
        'react/lib/ReactMount': 'React.addons.ReactMount',
        'react/lib/ReactInputSelection': 'React.addons.ReactInputSelection',
        'react/lib/LinkedStateMixin': 'React.addons.LinkedStateMixin',
        'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
        'react-router': 'ReactRouter',
        'history/lib': 'History',
        'history': 'History',
    },
```

I got  `Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined` when webpack require react/lib/ReactInputSelection.

Can anybody helps me ? Thanks.